# AppleReviewで送られてくるクラッシュログの解析について

Tags: swift, xcode

iOSアプリを審査に出したところ、クラッシュが起きるということでクラッシュログが送られきました。
私の環境やテスターの環境ではクラッシュしていないため、特定のデバイスで起きるクラッシュなのではないかと考えております。

そして、クラッシュログを以下の記事を参考にして解析してみました。

[【iOS】Appleから送られてきたクラッシュログを解析し、その結果を読み解く - Qiita](https://qiita.com/orimomo/items/9f88c740ad41cfd25328)

上記の記事に従って、Appleから送られてきたcrashログを変換し、読んでみるとファイル内は以下の様なものでした。
(アプリ名や識別子を一部隠しています。)

```
    {"app_name":"TestApp","timestamp":"2021-05-25 20:26:46.00 -0700","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx","adam_id":00000000,"build_version":"2","platform":2,"bundleID":"TestApp","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.5 (18E199)","incident_id":"FD178D30-6E7E-4F1A-B6A8-A38F57B1238A","name":"TestApp"}
    Incident Identifier: xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
    CrashReporter Key:   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
    Process:             TestApp [959]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/TestApp.app/TestApp
    Identifier:          TestApp
    Version:             2 (1.0.0)
    AppStoreTools:       12E262
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Foreground
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    Coalition:           TestApp [763]
    
    
    Date/Time:           2021-05-25 20:26:45.5716 -0700
    Launch Time:         2021-05-25 20:26:45.4202 -0700
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.5 (18E199)
    Release Type:        User
    Baseband Version:    n/a
    Report Version:      104
    
    Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a34d8acc
    Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
    Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
    Terminating Process: exc handler [959]
    Triggered by Thread:  6
    
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0:
    0   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae602a8 0x1dae1e000 + 271016
    1   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae6020c 0x1dae1e000 + 270860
    2   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae5f418 0x1dae1e000 + 267288
    3   libFontParser.dylib             0x00000001dae2547c 0x1dae1e000 + 29820
    4   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a11ec664 0x1a11d1000 + 112228
    5   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a14ed6a8 0x1a11d1000 + 3262120
    6   CoreText                        0x00000001a3cb25a4 0x1a3c61000 + 333220
    7   CoreText                        0x00000001a3c9dca8 0x1a3c61000 + 249000
    8   CoreText                        0x00000001a3cb0d10 0x1a3c61000 + 326928
    9   CoreText                        0x00000001a3c7fef0 0x1a3c61000 + 126704
    10  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c835b4 0x1a3c61000 + 140724
    11  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c9d60c 0x1a3c61000 + 247308
    12  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c9d47c 0x1a3c61000 + 246908
    13  CoreText                        0x00000001a3c889ec 0x1a3c61000 + 162284
    14  UIFoundation                    0x00000001a8b60250 0x1a8b2e000 + 205392
    15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2834bc0 0x1a176a000 + 17607616
    16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe63c 0x1a176a000 + 3753532
    17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5407ec 0x19f53c000 + 18412
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f542084 0x19f53c000 + 24708
    19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe5ac 0x1a176a000 + 3753388
    20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1aff120 0x1a176a000 + 3756320
    21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1aff298 0x1a176a000 + 3756696
    22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe6b8 0x1a176a000 + 3753656
    23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afe92c 0x1a176a000 + 3754284
    24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1afed44 0x1a176a000 + 3755332
    25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b010d8 0x1a176a000 + 3764440
    26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b0179c 0x1a176a000 + 3766172
    27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b088e8 0x1a176a000 + 3795176
    28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2834a88 0x1a176a000 + 17607304
    29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2875c20 0x1a176a000 + 17873952
    30  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a2cfc91c 0x1a2b95000 + 1472796
    31  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a2cfce00 0x1a2b95000 + 1474048
    32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2861c74 0x1a176a000 + 17792116
    33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1b06328 0x1a176a000 + 3785512
    34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af41b0 0x1a176a000 + 3711408
    35  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af1b08 0x1a176a000 + 3701512
    36  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af7ea0 0x1a176a000 + 3727008
    37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1af1664 0x1a176a000 + 3700324
    38  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1aee984 0x1a176a000 + 3688836
    39  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2375d7c 0x1a176a000 + 12631420
    40  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2375444 0x1a176a000 + 12629060
    41  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2376348 0x1a176a000 + 12632904
    42  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2387888 0x1a176a000 + 12703880
    43  TestApp                     0x0000000100a66618 AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 75288 (<compiler-generated>:0)
    44  TestApp                     0x0000000100a6688c @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 75916 (<compiler-generated>:0)
    45  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2330a08 0x1a176a000 + 12347912
    46  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a233249c 0x1a176a000 + 12354716
    47  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a23385e8 0x1a176a000 + 12379624
    48  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198c598 0x1a176a000 + 2237848
    49  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1ef5634 0x1a176a000 + 7910964
    50  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198d130 0x1a176a000 + 2240816
    51  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198cb38 0x1a176a000 + 2239288
    52  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198cf40 0x1a176a000 + 2240320
    53  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a198c77c 0x1a176a000 + 2238332
    54  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1994cc0 0x1a176a000 + 2272448
    55  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1e0304c 0x1a176a000 + 6918220
    56  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1f0e444 0x1a176a000 + 8012868
    57  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a19949b8 0x1a176a000 + 2271672
    58  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a17bc8a0 0x1a176a000 + 338080
    59  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a17bb220 0x1a176a000 + 332320
    60  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a17bc4c8 0x1a176a000 + 337096
    61  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2336788 0x1a176a000 + 12371848
    62  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1e2c6ac 0x1a176a000 + 7087788
    63  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeeaf5d8 0x1aeea5000 + 42456
    64  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeedad44 0x1aeea5000 + 220484
    65  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeebe6a4 0x1aeea5000 + 104100
    66  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aeedaa0c 0x1aeea5000 + 219660
    67  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5407ec 0x19f53c000 + 18412
    68  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5442dc 0x19f53c000 + 33500
    69  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aef02fa0 0x1aeea5000 + 384928
    70  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aef02c30 0x1aeea5000 + 384048
    71  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001aef03184 0x1aeea5000 + 385412
    72  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8cd848 0x19f82a000 + 669768
    73  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8cd744 0x19f82a000 + 669508
    74  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8cca48 0x19f82a000 + 666184
    75  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c6a28 0x19f82a000 + 641576
    76  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c61c0 0x19f82a000 + 639424
    77  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b6eae734 0x1b6eab000 + 14132
    78  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a23347e4 0x1a176a000 + 12363748
    79  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a233a054 0x1a176a000 + 12386388
    80  TestApp                     0x0000000100a5dcc4 main + 40132 (AppDelegate.swift:9)
    81  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019f582cf8 0x19f581000 + 7416

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 1:
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5521b0 0x19f53c000 + 90544
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f551ec4 0x19f53c000 + 89796
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f5527a8 0x19f53c000 + 92072
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea752768 0x1ea74f000 + 14184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea75974c 0x1ea74f000 + 42828

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cd28c4fc 0x1cd288000 + 17660
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cd28b884 0x1cd288000 + 14468
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8ccd10 0x19f82a000 + 666896
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c6bb0 0x19f82a000 + 641968
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f8c61c0 0x19f82a000 + 639424
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a0ba6fac 0x1a0b9f000 + 32684
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a0ba6e78 0x1a0b9f000 + 32376
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a23e938c 0x1a176a000 + 13104012
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a0d182fc 0x1a0b9f000 + 1544956
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea750c00 0x1ea74f000 + 7168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759758 0x1ea74f000 + 42840

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a34d8acc 0x1a34a1000 + 228044
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a34d8acc 0x1a34a1000 + 228044
2   TestApp                     0x0000000100ae6fdc closure #2 in ViewController.viewDidLoad() + 602076 (<compiler-generated>:0)
3   TestApp                     0x0000000100ae701c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Bool) -> () + 602140 (<compiler-generated>:0)
4   TCC                             0x00000001e2a02924 0x1e29ff000 + 14628
5   TCC                             0x00000001e2a06ff0 0x1e29ff000 + 32752
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001ea785168 0x1ea76a000 + 110952
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001ea778a70 0x1ea76a000 + 60016
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f540874 0x19f53c000 + 18548
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f55cf54 0x19f53c000 + 134996
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f552d1c 0x19f53c000 + 93468
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea7527dc 0x1ea74f000 + 14300
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea75974c 0x1ea74f000 + 42828

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ea759744 0x1ea74f000 + 42820

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x8000000100b80ab0   x1: 0x0000000282c3ee80   x2: 0x0000000000000007   x3: 0x00000001aef3d238
    x4: 0x00000000000062dc   x5: 0x000000016f6ee5b0   x6: 0x0000000000000073   x7: 0x0000000000000850
    x8: 0x000000000000007f   x9: 0x00000000000007fb  x10: 0x00000000000007fd  x11: 0x000000000000005e
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x00000000ae00203b  x14: 0x00000000ae202800  x15: 0x0000000000002800
   x16: 0x000000002e200000  x17: 0x00000001aef449b0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x8000000100b80ab0
   x20: 0x000000016f6ee640  x21: 0x0000000100b7a0f4  x22: 0x0000000000000028  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x00000000000005ee  x25: 0x000000000000000b  x26: 0x0000000000000002  x27: 0x0000000100b80060
   x28: 0x000000016f6ee680   fp: 0x000000016f6ee730   lr: 0x00000001a34d8acc
    sp: 0x000000016f6ee680   pc: 0x00000001a34d8acc cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault
```

上記のログを読む限り、AppDelegate.swiftの9行目あたりに問題があるのかもしれない、という点くらいしか分からないのですが
実際のAppDelegate.swiftの9行目は、以下の様にクラス定義をしているだけの箇所です。

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SwiftyStoreKit
import Foundation



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

これらの情報からクラッシュの原因を特定できるものなのでしょうか？

このプロジェクトでは、サードパーティのライブラリを使用しているため、「Enable Bitcode」をNoに設定しております。「Download Debug Symbols」を押すと、「No dSYMs were found for Version...」と表示されます。これがクラッシュログが正しくシンボル化できない原因の1つなのではないかと考えています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 適切なsymbolicateが出来ていないのでわかりにくいのですが、クラッシュログで一番に気にすべきところは「自分のアプリ名が出てくる一番上の行」になります。あなたの場合は、`43  TestApp                     0x0000000100a66618 AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 75288 (<compiler-generated>:0)`の行。これでこのCrashが`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`の中で起こっていることがわかります。そこからいろいろな処理が間接的に呼ばれて`libFontParser.dylib`でフォントがらみの処理を行っている最中にCrashしているとまでは言えます。ただし、`Triggered by Thread:  6`とあるので、Thread 0だけ見ていても直接の原因はわからないでしょう。`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`の中で間接的にフォントの読み出しが行われるような処理はありますか?

Comment: 適切なsymbolicateが出来ていないというのは、私のクラッシュログの変換の手順が間違っているのが理由だと思いますか？それとも、それ以外でも適切にsymbolicateできない場合がありますでしょうか？コーディング上でのフォント絡みの処理で言えば、ダークモード対応くらいしかしてないと思います。ダークモード対応もdidFinishLaunchingWithOptionsの中で行ってはいないと思います。見落としがあるかもしれませんが、他はStoryboad上でフォント周りの処理は行っていると思います。Thread:  6まで本文に追記しました。

Comment: 私自身は今までAppleからクラッシュログが送られて来たことがないので、手順の詳細についてはコメントし兼ねます。ただし、適切なsymbolicateが出来ているとどのような出力になるかは[Appleのサイト](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report)に記載がありますので、同じ手順をとったかなど確認して見てください。「フォント絡みの処理」については、テキストをどこかに表示する、だけでも「フォント絡みの処理」が走ります。なお、『クラッシュログで一番に気にすべきところは「自分のアプリ名が出てくる一番上の行」』と言うのは変わりません。`2   TestApp                     0x0000000100ae6fdc closure #2 in ViewController.viewDidLoad() + 602076 (<compiler-generated>:0)`に該当するところがどこなのか、探してみると良いでしょう。

Comment: 正しくシンボル化できない理由を探していて、Windows→Organizer→「Download Debug Symbols」を押すと良いという記事を見かけました。実際に押してみたところ、「No dSYMs were found for Version 1.0.0 Build 2.」というエラーが出ました。これは、アプリの「Enable Bitcode」がオフになっている時に出るエラーらしいのですが、これを消す方法はご存知ないでしょうか？サードパーティのライブラリを使用しており、Enable BitcodeをONにした状態だとビルドができないのでOFFにするしかないので八方塞がりです。

Comment: 残念ながら、その辺は詳しくないです。ただ、適切なsymbolicateが出来ているとしても、追加して分かる情報は「iOSのシステム内のどこでクラッシュしているか」なので、有用な情報が取れるかどうかは運次第です。まずは現在位のクラッシュログにヒントが出ている`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`と`ViewController.viewDidLoad()`を徹底的に調べてみるしかないでしょう。